# transposing acrosss a db column based on other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I need to pivot around a column but it has to be dependent on another column.

```
G_ID    COL_ONE  COL_TWO   COL_THREE    
146157  228830   null      228828
146157  228831   228830    228863
```

I have G_ID which is constant across the way I want to pivot. I want to show

```
G_ID    COL_THREE_1    COL_THREE_2 
146157  228863         228828
```

Now the business rules here is where it get fun and I need some pointers.

- I have to read COL_TWO when it is not null. (first one is 228830)
- Show COL_THREE in this row in COL_THREE_1 as the output (228863)
- Read the value of COL_TWO and then map that to COL_ONE on another row and then output the COL_THREE in this row to COL_THREE_2 (228828)

In this example I am only showing one G_ID but there are lots so I need something that will work over multiple G_IDs

Any pointers on this. Ive finding this a bit of a challenge so am happy to have a go but just need some pointers on where to start

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand much of your requirements (TWO_ID, ONE_ID etc), I find that quite unclear. Could you please add concrete examples ?

Comment: of course. Ive just updated. The numbers I am using are real numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, I guess self join will suffice :

```
with tab (G_ID,COL_ONE,COL_TWO,COL_THREE) as ( 
  select 146157,228830,null,228828 from dual union all
  select 146157,228831,228830,228863 from dual union all
  select 146158,228831,null,228829 from dual union all
  select 146158,228832,228831,228864 from dual)
--------------------------
-- End if Data preparation
--------------------------
select a.g_id, b.col_three col_three_1, a.col_three col_three_2
  from tab a 
  join tab b on a.COL_ONE = b.COL_TWO and a.G_ID = b.G_ID
 where b.col_two is not null;
```

Output:

```
|   G_ID | COL_THREE_1 | COL_THREE_2 |
|--------|-------------|-------------|
| 146157 |      228863 |      228828 |
| 146158 |      228864 |      228829 |
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about self joins

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try just using aggregate functions (I could not figure out how to do this using `pivot` clause):

```
select t.g_id,
       min(t.val_three) keep (dense_rank first order by t.val_two) VAL_THREE_1,
       max(t.val_three) keep (dense_rank last order by t.val_two) VAL_THREE_2
from my_table t
group by t.g_id
;
```

I added more values to `my_table` to give a better view:

```
G_ID    VAL_ONE  VAL_TWO   VAL_THREE    
146157  228830   null      228828
146157  228831   228830    228863
146234  228832   null      228567
146234  228833   228835    228789
```

I then get:

```
    G_ID    VAL_THREE_1 VAL_THREE_2
1   146157  228863      228828
2   146234  228789      228567
```